# How to add the url and urldate to \footcite output?

Tags: biblatex, biber

Here's the example that does almost everything that I need it to do.
The only thing that is missing is that I need the url and urldate to show when using \footcite for online sources.
I'd like to achieve something like this:

Laubheimer, *Virtual Tours: High Interaction Cost, Moderate Usefulness*, 30. Aug. 2020. url:
https://www.nngroup.com/articles/virtual-tours/ (besucht am 18.01.2021).

I would greatly appreciate any pointers, thanks!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-ibid,sorting=none,backend=biber,labeldateparts]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptobibmacro{cite:title}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}{}
  {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printlabeldateextra}}}{}{}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{einstein,
        author = {Albert Einstein},
        title = {the true about tree},
        journaltitle = {Annalen der Physik},
        year = {1905},
        volume = {322},
        number = {10},
        pages = {891--921}
    }
   @Online {laubpage,
    author = {Laubheimer, Page},
    title = {Virtual Tours: High Interaction Cost, Moderate Usefulness},
    date = {2020-08-30},
    year = {2020},
    file = {:./references/articles-virtual-tours-.html:html},
    url = {https://www.nngroup.com/articles/virtual-tours/},
    urldate = {2021-01-18}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}


Cite this\footcite[Vgl.][S. 32-33]{einstein} and this\footcite{laubpage} please.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `url` field is printed by the `doi+eprint+url` macro, which is defined in the `standard.bbx` file. To use it with `authortitle` style (and similar) it must be imported into the macro `title`:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptobibmacro{cite:title}{%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \iffieldundef{labelyear}{}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printlabeldateextra}}%
    \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
}{}{}
```